# Prove trigonometric identity, hence or otherwise find the general solution

Tags: trigonometry, proof-verification, trigonometric-series

The following question requires one to prove the below trigonometric identity $$\cos 3x = 4\cos ^3 x - 3\cos x$$

Hence, or otherwise, find the general solution of the following equation $$(4\cos ^2 x - 3)(4\cos ^2 3x - 3)(4\cos ^2 9x -3) = 1$$

---

After proving the latter over a couple back and forth steps (I'll be honest, I took longer than I should've), I've proceeded to the second part of the question; key term in the question I thought is *hence*. Thus I had to somehow use the previous proof and simplify the above equation.

I attempted to make the relation between $\cos3x$ and $4\cos ^2 3x -3$ however can't seem to break anything valuable.

---

I would greatly appreciate any hints that could help me move forward with this question, is there an expansion that I am to be made aware of; does $2n\pi \pm \alpha$ take place in the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We start with
\begin{align*}
4\cos ^2 x - 3)(4\cos ^2 3x - 3)(4\cos ^2 9x -3) & = 1\\
\cos x (4\cos ^2 x - 3)(4\cos ^2 3x - 3)(4\cos ^2 9x -3) & = \cos x\\
(4\cos ^3 x - 3\cos x)(4\cos ^2 3x - 3)(4\cos ^2 9x -3) & = \cos x\\
(\cos 3x)(4\cos ^2 3x - 3)(4\cos ^2 9x -3) & = \cos x\\
(4\cos ^3 3x - 3\cos 3x)(4\cos ^2 9x -3) & = \cos x\\
\cos 9x (4\cos ^2 9x -3) & = \cos x\\
\cos 27 x & = \cos x.
\end{align*}
Now solve.

Comment: That is a much more intuitive way to work it out. Thanks @AnuragA going to try completing the rest myself (not sure if you can put an answer under a hidden container like a spoiler or whatnot).

Comment: $$\cos(27x)=\cos(x)$$ gives us the following solutions: $$x_1=2\pi n$$, $$x_2=2\left(\pi n-\frac{3\pi}{7}\right)$$, $$x_3=2\left(\pi n-\frac{5\pi}{14}\right)$$, $$x_4=2\left(\pi n-\frac{2\pi}{7}\right)$$, $$x_5=2\left(\pi n-\frac{3\pi}{14}\right)$$ with $n$ is the element of Z -> the set of integers

Answer (score 0):

Verify the following identity:$\cos 3x = 4\cos ^3 x - 3\cos x$

$$\cos (3x) = 4\cos ^3 (x) - 3\cos (x)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\cos (3x) = 4\left(\frac{1}{4}(3\cos(x)+\cos(3x))\right) - 3\cos (x)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\cos(3x)=4\left(\frac{3\cos(x)+\cos(3x)}{4}\right)-3\cos(x)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\cos(3x)=\frac{4(3\cos(x)+\cos(3x))}{4}-3\cos(x)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\cos(3x)=\frac{4}{4}(3\cos(x)+\cos(3x))-3\cos(x)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\cos(3x)=3\cos(x)+\cos(3x)-3\cos(x)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\cos(3x)=3\cos(x)-3\cos(x)+\cos(3x)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\cos(3x)=0+\cos(3x)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\cos(3x)=\cos(3x)$$

Q.E.D.